# How to traslate this query of mongodb to monk

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

query of mongodb:

```
db.essay.find({_id:{$lt:ObjectId("551d558aebce3712baa9f2a8")}}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(1)
```

I want to use it in monk, i have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var monk = require('monk'); 
var db = monk('localhost:27017/mydb'); 
var collection = db.get('essay'); 
collection.find(
    { _id: { $lt: ObjectId("551d558aebce3712baa9f2a8") } },
    { limit: 1, sort: { _id : -1 } }, function (err, obj) { }
);
```

Comment: Did you try the above?

Comment: var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/mydb'); var collection = db.get('essay');
 collection.find({},{},function(e,obj){    at least like this..

Comment: The concept should be the same, I've edited my answer to include the node.js part.